# I am trying to fetch the data with the below code but it is giving an error is there any other method

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import time


url = 'https://www.mciindia.org/CMS/information-desk/indian-medical-register'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)


driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-sm-4']//button[@class='multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default']").click()

driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(),'2015')]")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='doctor_advance_Details']").click()


soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table',{'id':'doct_info5'})
headers = [ header.text.strip() for header in table.find_all('th') ]

next_page = True
while next_page == True:
    soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table',{'id':'doct_info5'})
try:
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        if len(row.find_all('td')) == 7:
            data = row.find_all('td')

            name = data[4].text.strip()
            root_url = data[6].a['href'].split("'")[1]
            id_url = data[6].a['href'].split("'")[3]

            link = root_url + 'ViewDetails.aspx?ID=' + id_url

            print ('Link: %s' %(link))
except:
     pass

time.sleep(5)
try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Next')]").click()
except:
    print ('No more pages')
    next_page=False

driver.close()
```

The code written above is not clicking on the year using xpath I tried to click the specific years to fetch the data is there any other way to fetch the data from the above link. Is there any other way than selenium webdriver..can we just extract using beautifulsoup and requests.

Comment: Which error do you see?

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="doctor_advance_Details">...</button> is not clickable at point (509, 659). Other element would receive the click: <label class="radio">...</label> @DebanjanB